# Loop through column pairs and load to an array

Tags: r

I have a dataframe : data containing pairs of columns that represent X, Y values.

I need to convert the pairs into individual matrices. Another way of thinking is to say loop over columns step 2.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
for (set in  1:4){
    data[set] <-cbind(data[, set], data[,set+1])  
}
```

But I receive the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , set + 1) : undefined columns selected
```

Also, I don't know the range 1:4 in advance, is there a way I can get the count of the last column i.e. data.width?

Later on I need to pass each individual matrix into a function.

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Did you check if you really have two `,` in `data[,set+1]`?

Comment: Use combination of `ncol`, `seq`, no need for loops.

Comment: Can you elaborate on ncol, seq a little please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this example:

```
#dummy data
x <- matrix(1:24,ncol=8)

#dummy function
myfunc<-function(x,y)x+y

#use myfunc per 2 columns
sapply(seq(1,ncol(x)-2,2),
       function(i)myfunc(x[,i],x[,i+1]))
```

**EDIT:**

```
#dummy data
x <- matrix(1:24,ncol=8)

#dummy plot function
myfunc<-function(x,y){
  plot(x,y,
       xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),
       ylim=c(min(y),max(y)))
}

#use myfunc per 2 columns
sapply(seq(1,ncol(x)-2,2),
       function(i)myfunc(x[,i],x[,i+1]))
```

Comment: The function takes in a whole matrix containing 2 columns.  I don't care too much about individual row values.

Comment: This is just an example, `myfunc` can be anything. If you can be more specific about what you intend to do with selected 2 columns, we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it with :

```
width <- ncol(data) -2

for (set in  1:width){

x < - set
y <- set +1 


data[set] <-cbind(data[, x], data[,y])
```

}